# MVP . Не излишества ли это

Tags: android, mvp

как думаете в такой ситуации в рамках MVP чем выгоден такой подход: Есть активити и презентер. На активити кнопка `Add` , эта кнопка должна введенные ФИО добавить в БД.  И как MVP говорит, активити должен просто вызвать соответствующий метод презентера. Так и делаем . `presenter.add();` А потом презентер уже сам у активити вызывает метод `get` по которому он получает объект ФИО который сформировался из введенных полей.    ТЕперь выходит у активити есть метод `get`, который эти поля возвращает и его вызывает презентер. Чем это хуже если бы при нажатии на  кнопку, активити сама  передала бы сразу эти поля. Это итак очевидно, что эта кнопка должна передать в презентер данные. Иначе быть не может. А там уже презентер решит переполнена ли БД или еще что там. Мне кажется что они в погоне за тем, чтобы избавить активити от логики, начинают борщить. Даже если мне придется подключить другую вью , то там будет кнопка add и от нее презентер будет ждать данные. всё вроде логично. А то скажи презентору нажали кнопку для добавления пользователей, а он уже решит , что делать. ЯСное дело он обратится за данным.  Допустим сложные ситуации, когда это тяжелые данные. Тогда презентер создаст поток и в рамках доп потока начнет их брать. Я думаю, если вью итак должен передавать презентору данные и если он способен это делать (т.е. это не длительный процесс), то нет смысла в этих геттерах, проще сразу передавать объект.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    findViewById(R.id.add).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            presenter.add();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.clear).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            presenter.clear();
        }
    });

}

public UserData getUserData() {
    UserData userData = new UserData();
    userData.setName(editTextName.getText().toString());
    userData.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
    return userData;
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотите узнать? Текст трудно читать.

Comment: Я считаю, что геттер выдающий данные из полей в активити не должен быть. Но думал, что для этого надо сразу отдавать данные в презентор. Но мне дали достаточно интересный ответ, сейчас ознакомлюсь с ним получше.

Answer (score 2):

В активити не должно быть геттера для данных из его полей. При этом в презентере уже должны быть эти данные в момент нажатия на кнопку `Add`. Сделать это можно если в презентер отсылать всё введённое в поля ввода сразу после события ввода.

Если очень кратко и без сторонних библиотек типа `rxJava`, кои тут, конечно, сильно всё упростят, можно сделать так:

```
editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
editTextName.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        presenter.onNameChanged(s.toString());
    }
});
```

Соответственно в презентере будет переменная для имени и при вызове `Add` ему не надо будет обращаться ко вью за данными.

Comment: Круто) и радует, то что моё подозрение оказалось не ложным) . Но это получается схоже с тем, что я при нажатии на add передам это текстовое поле. Ведь всё равно тут вью берет на себя ответственность за передачу введенных в него данных. Чем хуже передать их в конце ввода, при нажатии на add , а не передавать по одной букве по мере набора?

Comment: И вообще, в рамках  MVP, ведь считается правильным, что вью оповещает, а презентер потом приходит за данными. А по Вашему получается, что вью и  сразу передает данные.

Comment: Если подобные геттеры держать в интерфейсе, это конечно лучше, но всё равно, думаю, сути вопроса не меняет.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, я тут с братом(программистом) посовещался) и пришли к выводу, что вы предлагаете костыль))) Т.е. в  MVP  презентер должен обращаться в геттер (вынесенный в интерфейс) за данными.  Если же вью сразу дает данные , то это MVC , и в какой то ситуации он выгоднее, особенно в данной. Но всё зависит от ситуации. Предложенное Вами, это костыль DataBinding'a или же 'ручная' реализация реактивности. Как вы думаете)) может вы давно пересели на rxJava, реактивность удобна и решили, что если нет rxJava, то будем реактивность реализовывать сами?))